# How to add '>' to every new line in a string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string

I have a text area on a UI and I need the user to type in Markdown. I need to make sure that each line they type will start with `>` as I want to view everything the typed as a blockquote when they preview it.

So for example if they type in:

```
> some text user <b>typed</b>

another line
```

When the markdown is rendered, only the fist line is a blockquote. The rest is plain text outside the blockquote.

Is there a way I can check each line and add the > if it is missing.

Things I have tried:

1. I tried removing all `>` characters and replacing each `\n` with a `\n>`. This however messed up the markdown as the user can also type in `<b>bold text</b>`.
2. I have a loop that checks for the `>` character after every new line. I just don't know how to insert the `>` if its missing.

Loop code:

```
 var match = /\r|\n/.exec(theString);
 if (match) {
     if (theString.charAt(match.index)!='>'){
         // don't know how to ad the character
     }
 }
```

3. I also though that maybe I can enforce the `>` in the textarea, but that research got me nowhere. As in, I don't think that is possible.
4. I also thought, what if the user types multiple `>>>>`. At that stage I was thinking about it too much and said I'd leave out cases like that as maybe that is the user's intention.

If anyone has any suggestions and/or alternative solutions it would be very much appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: A simple search and replace for "\r\n" with "\r\n>" should do it, then you just need to check the first character is a ">".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to insert `>` to the beginning of each line, if it doesn't exist:

```js
const input = `> some text user <b>typed</b>
another line
another line 2
> another line 3`;
const output = input.replace(/^(?!>)/gm, '> ');
console.log(output);
```

The pattern `^(?!>)` means: match the beginning of a line, which is not followed by `>`.

If you only want to insert `>`s where lines have text already, then also lookahead for non-whitespace in the line:

```js
const input = `> some text user <b>typed</b>

another line

another line 2

> another line 3`;
const output = input.replace(/^(?!>)(?=[^\n]*\S)/gm, '> ');
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Absolute life saver. Thank you so much. This is perfect :)

Comment: Your first suggestion is working perfect. I need the user to be able to put in a blank lines too, so they need the `>` character too. It's just so they can space things out and format their text :) Thanks a million again.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with replace (first thing you tried). In order to insert literal `>` in HTML, you have to [escape](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#autoescape) it.

Just replace `\n` with `\n&gt;` and you're all set.